# PHP while loop is giving me a random number of results

Tags: php, while-loop, fgets

this code below is supposed to pick 5 random members from a text file and display them one after the other:

```
function display() {
 $open_file = fopen("members.txt", 'r');
 $members = explode("*", fgets($open_file));
 $members_num = count($members);
 $i=1;
 shuffle($members);
 while($i <= 5) {
   $details = explode("|", $members[$i++]);
   if(!empty($details[0])) {
   echo <<<EOF
    $details[0] $details[1] $details[2] 
EOF;
}
 }
  fclose($open_file);
}

ob_start();
display();
$display = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$content=<<<EOF
 some text here $display more text
 <br>
 etc.
EOF;

echo $content;
```

This is the content of members.txt:

```
*James Johnson|USA|Male|1*Mary Reis|Germany|Female|2*Lin Xi|China|Male|3*Jessica Andrew|UK|Female|4*
```

The problem is that it wont always display 5, from time to time it displays only 4 and some other times 6. Why is that? How can I fix it so it displays only 5 ALWAYS?

Thank you.

Comment: can you tell what  members.txt contains

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. I just edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have `*` at the end of the line, one of the elements of `$members` will be an empty string. When you get to that element, `explode('|', $members[$i++])` will return the array `['']`, so `if(!empty($details[0]))` will skip it. But since you incremented `$i`, that causes you to display only 4 members.

I can't see any way that your code could display 6 members, though.

The fix is to only use `*` between elements, not after them. Or remove the empty string from `$members`.

```
$members = array_filter($members);
```

Comment: I found your logic's  are too strong.+10.Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: That filter should go before or after the shuffle?

Comment: It doesn't matter.